# Template in my custom component not working in app.component.html

Tags: angular

please click on each link to understand my question

[first created my custom Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqDVK.png)

[added the component in app module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIQ9e.png)

[when i use my custom component in appcomponent.html browser unable to retrive my html in selector and template of my customer component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuppU.png)

Comment: Please add your code here.

Comment: import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component(
    {
        selector: 'course',
        template: '<h1>Course</h1>'
    }
)
mycustom class
export class CoursesComponent
{

}

Comment: import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './Courses.Component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: appcomponent.html
<Course></Course>

Answer (score 0):

you've probably should have got warning like:

```
WARNING in ./src/app/Courses.Component.ts
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem 
with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing.
```

Because you have capital letter C in component here:

`import { CoursesComponent } from './Courses.Component';`

Please try:

`import { CoursesComponent } from './Courses.component';`

Answer (score 0):

I think that's enough for a component to work. Can you show your errors in the log of browser?. In Angular2+ you should use `ng generate component componentname` to create a component, see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#usage).